# how can I reliably stream data out of a matlab program?

Tags: matlab

I have to create a matlab program that gets and transforms streaming data it receives from a sensor. It needs, in turn, to push out its output data stream, to another application. Is there some matlab command/api that can be used for piping out this continuous output stream from matlab?

http? process piping? other?

Answer (score 1):

You can stream using UDP, but it's really really crappy.  I have had many issues with this.  I was not not able to stream 1 megabyte / second of float data without dropping packets left and right.  I actually switched to the open source program octave http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/ which is matlab compatible (your .m code just runs as is) and can handle fast UDP streams way better.

If you are doing sensor control you should probably stick with TCP.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize octave was code-level compatible. I actually figured I'd stream to a scala program through plain OS piping - push the matlab output to stdout and plug that into scala's stdin - or run the matlab process from within scala and read its stdout stream in the scala program.